# VSCode C project run fails

Tags: c, visual-studio-code

I've ported a simple C project which used a makefile that built the files individually to VSCode where compilation fails. It seems to be related to what's included in the build, but I can't seem to get it to work correctly. I'm using ** to specify recursive search, but it seems as if the build command generated isn't actually including the files in the build. I've created a minimal reproduction of the issue [in this repo](https://github.com/angles-n-daemons/vscode_c_debug) and have included the code in this post:

```
project layout

---  .vscode
    |-- c_cpp_properties.json
    |-- tasks.json
--- src
    |-- foo
    |   |-- foo.c
    |   --- foo.h
    --- main.c

3 directories, 3 files
```

```c
// main.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include "foo/foo.h"

int main() {
   foo();
   return 0;
}
```

```c
// foo.h
#ifndef cproject_foo_h
#define cproject_foo_h

void foo();

#endif
```

```c
// foo.c
#include "foo.h"
#include <stdio.h>

void foo() {
    printf("Hello, World!");
}
```

```json
// c_cpp_properties.json
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Mac",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**"
            ],
            "defines": [],
            "macFrameworkPath": [
                "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks"
            ],
            "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/clang",
            "cStandard": "c17",
            "cppStandard": "c++17",
            "intelliSenseMode": "macos-clang-x64"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

```json
// tasks.json
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: clang build active file",
            "command": "/usr/bin/clang",
            "args": [
                "-fcolor-diagnostics",
                "-fansi-escape-codes",
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "Task generated by Debugger."
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}
```

Below is the build failure, I'm struggling to understand why the includePath isn't working. Any guidance would be appreciated.

```
 *  Executing task: C/C++: clang build active file 

Starting build...
/usr/bin/clang -fcolor-diagnostics -fansi-escape-codes -g /Users/godzilla/vscode_c_debug/src/main.c -o /Users/godzilla/vscode_c_debug/src/main
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_foo", referenced from:
      _main in main-d46097.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Build finished with error(s).
```

Comment: what's the output of `clang --version`?

Comment: is the problem not that you're only building the active file? You have two translation units and you're only building one and haven't specified the built other one to link to?

Comment: `c_cpp_properties.json` is used for intellisense.  And `Undefined symbols` is a linker error.  The problem is in the `tasks.json` which is used to compile stuff.

Comment: clang version:

Apple clang version 14.0.3 (clang-1403.0.22.14.1)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin22.6.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin

Comment: Is there no means for specifying the build operate recursively? I could have the build run the make command, but then I'm curious whether the debugger would actually work

Comment: @starball that's correct, I misinterpreted the responsibility of c_cpp_properties. I'd like to build a whole C project, with the ability to debug. If possible, I'd like to just specify some way to build the entire source directory and its subdirectories - though I'm not sure that it's possible in vs code

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the way forward for myself was to point the build task to use the existing Makefile (instead of the c compiler) which handled recursively building the c files.

From there, I had to modify the launch targets so that I could debug my code. It worked decently, though it seems imperfect. Feel free to look at the changes in [this commit](https://github.com/angles-n-daemons/vscode_c_debug/commit/eab1d537cec0a53513d9716f41d874f028e3370d).